# Гугл таблицы. Итоговая сумма по разным валютам

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть колонка с разными суммами.
Ячейки отформатированы в соответствии с используемой валютой (рубли или евро).
Нужно общий итог считать без ввода дополнительного столбца с хранением прямого указания валюты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тоже интересует. Поможет кто-то?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, что вы хотите получить в результате, приведите пример и т. д.